# Adding text field or text box to wordpress category page

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I want to add text field or text box to wordpress category page to display content at the end of the page. It could be text box or text field. I am struggling with which file I have to edit.

Comment: do to want to add text field in front-end ?

Comment: depending on your theme. If you hava a category.php, try there. Maybe this link will help https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the category.php and could use the [Category description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description) to show different texts for each category.

```
<!-- Category output -->

<!-- Category Description Output -->
<div id="my-category-text">
  <?php echo category_description(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is adding another metabox in the Admin page of categories.

Here is an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/add-meta-box-to-category-edit-screen) that further explores what you may be looking for.